# The solution of only one equation being recorded, when all solutions should be recorded

Tags: differential-equations

I have the following code

```
lst = Table[
X[t_] := a Cos[t];
Y[t_] := Sin[t];
sols = {
 NDSolve[{D[{u[t], v[t]}, 
     t] == {{X[t], Y[t]}, {Y[t], -X[t]}}.{u[t], v[t]}, {u[0], 
     v[0]} == {1, 0}}, {u, v}, {t, 0, 10}],
 NDSolve[{D[{u[t], v[t]}, 
     t] == {{X[t], Y[t]}, {Y[t], -X[t]}}.{u[t], v[t]}, {u[0], 
     v[0]} == {0, 1}}, {u, v}, {t, 0, 10}]};
{a, Tr[{u[t], v[t]} /. sols] /. t -> 2 \[Pi]}, {a, 0, 1, 0.001}];

 ListPlot[lst, AxesLabel -> {"a", "Trace at 2\[Pi]"}]
```

What this code essentially does is that it calculates two different differential equations, which spit out column vectors as answers. It stores the two column vectors in "sols". I hoped that these two column vectors would be stored as a $2\times 2$ matrix. Then the code plots the trace of this matrix at a fixed time against $a$, which is an arbitrary parameter.

My advisor noticed that the trace values being generated were not correct. On playing with the code, I realized that the **"sols" was not recording the solution of the second differential equation at all**. Moreover, the "Tr" function is just adding up the sum of the elements of the solution of the first differential equation. Where am I going wrong? How should I fix this?

I tried using the "Trace" function instead of "Tr", but that didn't generate a plot at all.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues with your code. The biggest issue is that you are coding in a procedural style which is complicating your code.  Instead of explaining all the issues I have transformed the solution at a functional approach.

`x` is dependent on `a` and `t` so lets define it as such.

```
ClearAll[x, y]
x[t_, a_] := a Cos[t]
y[t_] := Sin[t]
```

Then the `NDSolve` becomes less complicated as you do not have attempt to control the steps in `a`.

```
sol =
  NDSolve[
     {
      D[{u[t, a], v[t, a]}, t] ==
       {{x[t, a], y[t]}, {y[t], -x[t, a]}}.
        {u[t, a], v[t, a]},
      {u[First@#, a], v[First@#, a]} == #
      },
     {u, v},
     {t, 0, 10}, {a, 0, 1}] & /@ {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};

foo = {u[t, a], v[t, a]} /. Flatten[sol, 1];

MatrixForm@foo
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you have your solution for `u` and `v` over the domains for `t` and `a`.  `u` and `v` can be plotted directly.

```
Plot3D[#, {t, 0, 10}, {a, 0, 1},
   PlotLegends -> {"u", "v"},
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[.8],
   AxesLabel -> {"t", "a"},
   PlotRange -> Full] & /@ foo
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

And finally you can plot the trace (`Tr`) for a fixed `t` over the domain of `a`.

```
Plot[Tr[foo /. {t -> 2 π}], {a, 0, 1},
 AxesLabel -> {"a", "Trace at t = 2π"}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Also plot the trace over the domain of `t` and `a`.

```
Plot3D[Tr[foo], {t, 0, 10}, {a, 0, 1},
 AxesLabel -> {"t", "a", "Tr"},
 PlotRange -> Full]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

PS: You can also explore with `Manipulate`.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Tr[foo /. {t -> v}], {a, 0, 1},
  AxesLabel -> {"a", StringTemplate["Trace at t = `1`"]@v}],
 {v, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! My only concern is that it seems you haven't considered the second differential equation I had plugged in

Comment: The initial conditions in that differential equation are different- (0,1) instead of (1,0). That is the only difference

Comment: @freebird You are correct. LOL! See update.

Comment: If I understand the edit correctly, you're assigning ${u[0],v[0]}=={0,1}$ and ${u[1],v[1]}=={1,0}$. I, on the other hand, want both to be ${u[0],v[0]}$. Or does the code do exactly that? Sorry I'm not very comfortable with lists yet.

Comment: @freebird That is correct. You may change`First@#` to`0` in `NDSolve` for those initial conditions.

Comment: Thanks I did that. Should I also change the /@ {{1,0},{0,1}} part of the code? After changing FIrst@# to 0, there is no mention of @ in the rest of the code

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
lst = Table[X[t_] := a Cos[t];
   Y[t_] := Sin[t];
   sol1 = 
    NDSolve[{D[{u[t], v[t]}, 
        t] == {{X[t], Y[t]}, {Y[t], -X[t]}}.{u[t], v[t]}, {u[0], 
        v[0]} == {1, 0}}, {u, v}, {t, 0, 10}]; 
   sol2 = NDSolve[{D[{u[t], v[t]}, 
        t] == {{X[t], Y[t]}, {Y[t], -X[t]}}.{u[t], v[t]}, {u[0], 
        v[0]} == {0, 1}}, {u, v}, {t, 0, 10}];
   {a, Tr[{{u[2 Pi] /. First[sol1][[1]], 
       v[2 Pi] /. First[sol1][[2]]}, {u[2 Pi] /. First[sol2][[1]], 
       v[2 Pi] /. First[sol2][[2]]}}]}, {a, 0, 1, 0.001}];
ListPlot[lst, AxesLabel -> {"a", "Trace at 2\[Pi]"}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: I don't think this code works. The solution of the second differential equation is not being considered for some reason. On changing the initial conditions of the second differential equation, the graph of the trace remains unchanged

Comment: The code works, the result matches the Carl Woll code. Maybe you want something else?

Answer (score 0):

Why not make use of the vector/matrix capabilities of the ODE solvers, and use [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue) instead of [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve):

```
pf = ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {
    Z'[t] == {{X[t], Y[t]}, {Y[t], -X[t]}} . Z[t], (* matrix version *)
    Z[0] == {{1, 0},{0, 1}}
    },
    Tr[Z[2 Pi]], (* desired trace at 2 Pi *)
    {t, 0, 10},
    a
];
```

Visualization:

```
Plot[pf[a], {a, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! The ParametricNDSolveValue function simplifies the code a lot!

Comment: Hi! I was using this code, and it seemed to work fine. However, just as an experiment, I changed the initial conditions from {{1,0},{0,1}} to {{0,1},{1,0}}. Clearly, I have just changed the order of the initial conditions. The graph should have been the same. However, the graph changes wildly.

Comment: I fear that the two initial conditions, which give two different solutions, cannot be input like this. How should I correct it?

Comment: Haha I suppose that the trace will indeed change if the order of the initial conditions is changed?

Comment: @freebird Yes, the trace changes. Try using `Z[2 Pi]` instead of `Tr[Z[2 Pi]]` and compare the results from the two initial conditions.